# My app gets stopped when reaches certain part of the java code

Tags: java, android

I hope you had a good day,
I've started android app development and I've done tons of research and debugging and finally, I got the line of code which causes my app to stop on Android Studio, here's the full code

```
package com.example.numbershapesapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
class Number {
    int user_number;

    public int isTriangle(int user_number) {
        int i = 0, sum = 0,c=0;
        while (true) {
            sum += i;
            if (sum == user_number) {
                ++c;
                break;
            }
            if(sum > user_number){
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(c>0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public int isSquare(int user_number) {
        int i = 1,c=0,sq=0;
        while (true) {
            sq = i*i;
            if (sq == user_number) {
                c++;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(c>0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;

    }
}

    public void function(View view) {
       EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_number);
        Number myNum = new Number();
         myNum.user_number = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
         int num = myNum.user_number;
       if(myNum.isTriangle(num) == 1){
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"The number "+num+" is Triangular.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }else if(myNum.isSquare(num) == 1){
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,"The number "+num+" is Square.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       else
           {
          // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"The number "+num+" is neither Triangular nor Square",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Log.i("TEXT","no t no s");
       }
//       Log.i("done","DONE");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

In the Function, function(View view) all the statements work except for the else statement.
When my code has to execute the **else** part then my app crashes. Can you help me with that?

Again here's the specific piece of code which causes this issue.

```
      else
           {
          // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"The number "+num+" is neither Triangular nor Square",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Log.i("TEXT","no t no s");
       }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe the crash in more detail: Do you get an "Application Not Responding" dialog or an "Application has stopped" dialog? What gets printed to the logcat?

Comment: Yes, sir, it says "Application Not Responding" and           Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' is printed on the logcat.

Comment: What is in /data/anr/traces.txt?

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm not clear about your question but so I hereby answer to what I inferred.No the java file for this code is in: C:\Users\shivansh\AndroidStudioProjects\NumberShapesApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\numbershapesapp\MainActivity.java

Comment: "Application Not Responding" suggests there is still an infinite loop. What numbers are you putting in?

Comment: Here's the deal: when I put 16 it Toast's Square number which is expected when I put 6 it Toasts Triangular number which is also expected but when I put 5 which is neither a square number nor a triangular number then the  "Application Not Responding"  is triggered as we enter the else loop.@Joni

Comment: With the original code `isSquare(5)` is an infinite loop, but if you added the fix in my answer it is not. Try using a debugger to find the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

If `user_number` is not a perfect square, this is an infinite loop.

```
        while (true) {
            sq = i*i;
            if (sq == user_number) {
                c++;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

You could fix it by adding a similar check you have when checking for triangular numbers:

```
            if(sq > user_number){
                break;
            }
```

But a better solution might be replacing the loop with a bit of maths.

```
double root = Math.sqrt(user_number);
if (root == (int) root) {
   // user_number is square
}
```

Comment: Both of them did not seem to work, unfortunately, the app still closes when the else condition is triggered, I'm sorry sir but any other alternatives?